# How to set 2 different FK from different tables on PK with 2 columns

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables:

```
create table book (book_id int not null primary key, 
                   book_name char (100) unique) 

create table author (author_id int not null primary key,
                     authorname char (100) unique) 

create table bookauthor (book_id int, 
                         author_id int, 
                         CONSTRAINT pk_book_id PRIMARY KEY (book_id,author_id))
```

I want to set

- column `book.book_id` as fk to `bookauthor.book_id`
- column `author.author_id` as fk to `bookauthor.author_id`

Please remember that pk in `bookauthor` is on `book_id,author_id`.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Share your experiences :)

Comment: It's spelled `author` (with an `o`) - not `auther`

Answer (score 1):

Change your bookauther table to

```
create table bookauther (
    book_id int , 
    auther_id int, 
    CONSTRAINT pk_book_id PRIMARY KEY (book_id,auther_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES book(book_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (auther_id) REFERENCES auther(auther_id)

)
```

Have a look at [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [SQL FOREIGN KEY Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)